# BERT: TypeError 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, bert-language-model

I am using BERT and I have been stuck for 2 weeks on this error.

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I wrote an example to show you the problem.

```
from bert_nli import BertNLIModel
from transformers import *

if __name__ == '__main__':

    claim = 'Anna Paquin acted in a drama film from New Zealand.'
    context = "Anna Helene Paquin -LRB- -LSB- ˈpækwɪn -RSB- born 24 July 1982 -RRB- is a Canadian-born New Zealand actress . Born in Manitoba and brought up in Wellington , New Zealand , Paquin studied at Hutt Intermediate School and the Wellington Girls ' College in New Zealand before moving to Los Angeles during her youth where she studied at Windward School and went on to complete a year at Columbia University before leaving post-secondary to focus on her acting career . As a child , she beat 5000 candidates for the role of Flora McGrath in Jane Campion 's romantic drama film The Piano -LRB- 1993 -RRB- , despite having had little to no acting experience prior to getting the role . For her performance , she received the Academy Award for Best Supporting Actress at the age of 11 , making her the second-youngest Academy Award winner in Oscar history .   Paquin went on to become a successful child actress , receiving multiple Young Artist Award nominations for her roles in Fly Away Home -LRB- 1996 -RRB- , The Member of the Wedding -LRB- 1997 -RRB- , and A Walk on the Moon -LRB- 1999 -RRB- , and was nominated for a Screen Actors Guild Award for Outstanding Performance by a Cast in a Motion Picture for appearing in Cameron Crowe 's comedy-drama film Almost Famous -LRB- 2000 -RRB- . She played mutant superheroine Rogue in multiple films of the X-Men franchise and was nominated for a Saturn Award and a Screen Actors Guild Award for her performance in the first instalment .   Paquin is also known for playing the lead role of Sookie Stackhouse in the HBO vampire drama television series True Blood -LRB- 2008 -- 2014 -RRB- . For her performance in the series , Paquin won the Golden Globe Award for Best Performance by an Actress in a Television Series -- Drama in 2009 and was nominated for an additional Golden Globe Award in 2010 , as well as three Saturn Awards and a Screen Actors Guild Award in 2010 . Among other accolades , Paquin has been nominated for a Primetime Emmy Award , a Golden Globe Award , and a Screen Actors Guild Award for her work on the 2007 television film Bury My Heart at Wounded Knee and a Golden Globe Award for her work on the 2009 television film The Courageous Heart of Irena Sendler ."

    tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
    inputs = tokenizer.encode_plus(claim, context, return_tensors='pt')

    print(f"Tokens are {len(inputs['input_ids'][0])}.")


    bert_type = 'bert-base'
    model = BertNLIModel('D:/progettoML-WMR/BERT/output/{}.state_dict'.format(bert_type), bert_type=bert_type)

    sent_pairs = [(context, claim)]

    labels, probs = model(sent_pairs)
    print(labels)
    print(probs)
```

The output is

```
Tokens are 502.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/progettoML-WMR/BERT/example.py", line 21, in <module>
    labels, probs = model(sent_pairs)
  File "C:\Users\luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "d:\progettoML-WMR\BERT\bert_nli.py", line 81, in forward
    probs = self.ff(sent_pair_list[batch_idx:batch_idx+bs],checkpoint)[1].data.cpu().numpy()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I did some tests and found that if I reduce the length of the context variable (by eliminating a few words), the output is

```
Tokens are 479.
['entail']
[[0.00807868 0.9728094  0.01911202]]
```

***EDIT:** I noticed that the code only gives an error if the input length is between 501 and 512 tokens*

I'm working on colab with the GPU and I'm using a batch_size = 6.
Therefore the maximum length accepted by the model should be 512 (including the [CLS] tag and the 2 [SEP] tags).
However, it seems not to be so.

Could you help me understand what is the origin of this error? Thank you in advance.